# Sed to delete between delimiters but keep first delimter

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I need to delete everything between the second `=` in a string and the first `/` in a string, but keep the `=` in place. I've tried many, many things, the most recent of which is

```
sed -i 's/=[^/]*//
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add a sample input and what your expected output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started writing about look-ahead and look-behind assertions only to learn that sed doesn't support them! This should do the trick:

`sed -i 's!\(=[^=]*=\)[^/]*/!\1!'`

- Since we use `/` character in the regexp, we change delimiter of `s` command to `!`
- `\(=[^=]*=\)` is a capture group that matches one `=` character followed by zero or more other characters followed by another `=` character. This part is needed to make sure there are two `=` characters before the to-be-deleted substring as you said you need to
- `[^/]*/` matches whatever is between delimiters and the second delimiter
- `\1` replaces the whole matched string with whatever matched the capture group `\(=[^=]*=\)`

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you for the detailed explanation as well.

Comment: Is it possible to do this same thing but skip the first = in the line? So same command, only beginning with the second occurance of =.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, Jeff. Can you give some sample in/output?

Answer (score 2):

Based only on the text description, with no sample input/output, I came up with this:

```
$ echo "foo=bar=baz/quux" | sed 's/\(.*=.*\)=.*\/\(.*\)/\1=\2/'
foo=bar=quux
```

How close does that come to what you want?

Comment: My apologies for not having a desired output. I will be sure to include that in future post.   That said the output John shows above is exactly what I am looking for.  It seems to cut everything after the 2nd = to the / but it leaves the = in place  which is exactly my use case.  I will try it would live data when I get back to my computer later this evening. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution with `perl`

```
$ echo 'foo=bar=baz/quux' | perl -pe 's|^([^=]+=){2}\K[^=/]+/||'
foo=bar=quux

$ echo 'abc=foo=bar=baz/quux' | perl -pe 's|^([^=]+=){2}\K[^=/]+/||'
abc=foo=bar=baz/quux
```

As can be seen from examples above, this restricts to deleting text only from 2nd `=` to `/`

- `^([^=]+=){2}\K` from start of line find `2` sequence of non-`=` text followed by `=`. The `\K` means positive lookbehind, not part of replacement string
- `[^=/]+/` means one or more non-`=/` characters ending with `/`

  - If such a text is found, it gets deleted

Same solution with `sed`

```
$ echo 'foo=bar=baz/quux' | sed -E 's|^(([^=]+=){2})[^=/]+/|\1|'
foo=bar=quux

$ echo 'abc=foo=bar=baz/quux' | sed -E 's|^(([^=]+=){2})[^=/]+/|\1|'
abc=foo=bar=baz/quux
```

It doesn't support lookahead/lookbehind constructs, so capture group used and backreferenced while replacing